# Autowiring a generic component in a generic superclass

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-boot

I have the following situation in a Spring 4.0 (using Spring Boot) environment:

**Mapping interface**:

```
public interface EntityModelMapper<ENTITY extends AbstractEntity, MODEL extends AbstractModel>{ }
```

**Mapping implementation**:

```
@Component
public class ProductEntityModelMapper implements EntityModelMapper<Product, ProductModel>{ }
```

**Service**:

```
public interface CrudService<MODEL extends AbstractModel>{ }
```

**And I want to do an abstract superclass service like this**:

```
public abstract AbstractCrudService<ENTITY extends AbstractEntity, MODEL extends AbstractModel> implements CrudService<MODEL>{

@Autowired
private EntityModelMapper<ENTITY, MODEL> mapper;

  public EntityModelMapper<ENTITY, MODEL> getMapper(){ 
      return mapper; 
  }
}
```

**So I can have implementations likes this**:

```
@Service
public ProductCrudService extends AbstractCrudService<Product, ProductModel>{

  public void someMethod(Product product){
    ProductModel model = getMapper().map(product);
  }

}
```

But Spring tells me it can't find qualifying beans of EntityModelMapper to inject in the service classes. Is this scenario possible and I'm doing something wrong or am I pushing the limits of Spring's dependecy injection?

Stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
 Error creating bean with name 'productCrudService':
 Injection of autowired dependencies failed;
 nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field:
 private com.flycatcher.seagull.mapper.EntityModelMapper 
com.flycatcher.seagull.facade.service.crud.AbstractCrudService.mapper;
 nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
 No qualifying bean of type [com.flycatcher.seagull.mapper.EntityModelMapper] found for dependency:
 expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.
 Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this: 
https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/03/spring-framework-4-0-and-java-generics
It is possible since Spring 4.0 version.

That didn't work me either. (same exception and Im using 4.2.3). 
So try to upgrade to the latest version - 4.2.6.

If it still doesn't work, 
you can instead use the @Qualifier annotation and autowire EntityModelMapper as an interface in your sub-class, and define getMapper as abstract:

```
  @Component
  @Qualifier("productEntityModelQualifier")
  public class ProductEntityModelMapper implements EntityModelMapper<Product, ProductModel>{ }
```

and then in ProductCrudService:

```
@Service
public ProductCrudService extends AbstractCrudService<Product, ProductModel>{

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("productEntityModelQualifier")
  EntityModelMapper<Product, ProductModel> mapper;

  @Override
  protected EntityModelMapper<Product, ProductModel> getMapper(){return mapper;}

  public void someMethod(Product product){
    ProductModel model = getMapper().map(product);
  }

}
```

Comment: Injecting the EntityModelMapper<Product, ProductModel> directly in the service implementation works for me. What I want to do is inject it in the abstract class so that each service implementation will have access to its specific EntityModelMapper implementation. (i.e ProductCrudService will have an EntityModelMapper<Product, ProductModel> ready at runtime.)

Comment: I understood what you want. Read the first paragraph of my answer